# List All Tables That Contain A Specific Employee Name

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a list of employee names, and a list of tables. I need to iterate all employee names and find which table(s) the employee name exists in. All of the tables to iterate exist on the same server and the same database.

Sample data structure

```
Create Table TableNamesToCheck (dbName varchar(15))

Insert Into TableNamesToCheck 
Values ('table1'), ('table2'), ('table3'), ('table4'), ('table5'), 
       ('table6'), ('table7'), ('table8'), ('table9'), ('table10')

Create Table EN (employeename varchar(100))

Insert Into EN 
Values ('Richard Marx'), ('Joseph Jones'), ('Mark Badcock'), 
       ('Frank Fins'), ('Richard James'), ('Fall Fren'), ('Hiu Hen')
```

Thank you @Giorgi --- I understand using Cursor for my tablenames, but how do I join the two tables, when their is no similar field to join the 2 tables on?  This is what I have (work in progress) if I understand what you are explaining this is my syntax, but it gives me the below error for each employee and each table...

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'employeename'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Richard'.

```
Declare @dbname varchar(25), @empname varchar(100), @sql varchar(Max)

Create Table TableNamesToCheck (dbName varchar(15))

Insert Into TableNamesToCheck 
Values ('table1'), ('table2'), ('table3'), ('table4'), ('table5'), 
   ('table6'), ('table7'), ('table8'), ('table9'), ('table10')

Create Table EN (employeename varchar(100))

Insert Into EN 
Values ('Richard Marx'), ('Joseph Jones'), ('Mark Badcock'), 
   ('Frank Fins'), ('Richard James'), ('Fall Fren'), ('Hiu Hen')


Declare c1 Cursor For
Select dbname
From TableNamesToCheck

Open c1
Fetch Next from c1 into @dbname

Declare c2 Cursor For
Select employeename 
From EN

Open c2
Fetch Next from c2 into @empname

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin

    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin

        Set @sql =  'Select '+@dbname+' From TableNamesToCheck where employeename IN (Select '+@empname+' from EN)'

        Exec (@sql)

    Fetch Next From c1 Into @dbname
    Fetch Next From c2 Into @empname

   End

End


Close c1
Close c2
Deallocate c1
Deallocate c2

Drop Table TableNamesToCheck
Drop Table EN
```

Comment: You will need cursor over tablenames table, and left join en table on table from tablenames. All this in dynamic query with exec function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but you might be looking for this :-

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @Sql       Varchar(Max)
        ,@Total     Int
        ,@RowId     Int
        ,@EmpName   Varchar(100)
        ,@Total2    Int
        ,@RowId2    Int
        ,@TableName Varchar(15)

Select   @Sql = ''
        ,@EmpName = ''
        ,@TableName = ''

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#TableNamesToCheck') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #TableNamesToCheck;
End

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#EN') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #EN;
End

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#EnTables') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #EnTables;
End

Create Table #TableNamesToCheck
(
     dbId           Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
    ,dbName         Varchar(15)
)

Create Table #EN 
(
     RowId          Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
    ,employeename   Varchar(100)
)

Create Table #EnTables
(
     Id             Int Identity(1,1) Primary Key
    ,EmployeeName   Varchar(100)
    ,dbName         Varchar(15)
)

Insert Into #TableNamesToCheck 
Values ('table1'), ('table2'), ('table3'), ('table4'), ('table5'), 
       ('table6'), ('table7'), ('table8'), ('table9'), ('table10')

Insert Into #EN 
Values ('Richard Marx'), ('Joseph Jones'), ('Mark Badcock'), 
       ('Frank Fins'), ('Richard James'), ('Fall Fren'), ('Hiu Hen')

Select   @Total = Count(1)
        ,@RowId = 1
From    #EN As en With (Nolock)

Select   @Total2 = Count(1)
        ,@RowId2 = 1
From    #TableNamesToCheck As et With (Nolock)

While (@RowId <= @Total)
Begin
    Select  @EmpName = en.employeename
    From    #EN As en With (Nolock)
    Where   en.RowId = @RowId

    While (@RowId2 <= @Total2)
    Begin
        Select  @TableName = et.dbName
        From    #TableNamesToCheck As et With (Nolock)
        Where   et.dbId = @RowId2

        Select  @Sql =  ' If Exists ' +
                        ' ( ' +
                            ' Select    1 ' +
                            ' From      ' + @TableName + ' As t With (Nolock) ' +
                            ' Where     t.employeename = ''' + @EmpName + ''' ' +
                            ' ) ' +
                        ' Begin ' +
                            ' Insert Into #EnTables(EmployeeName,dbName) ' +
                             ' Select    ''' + @EmpName + ''' ' +
                                        ' ,''' + @TableName + ''' ' +
                            ' End '
        ----Print(@Sql)
        Exec (@Sql)

        Select  @RowId2 = @RowId2 + 1
    End

    Select   @RowId = @RowId + 1
            ,@RowId2 = 1
            ,@EmpName = ''
            ,@TableName = ''
End

Select  *
From    #EnTables As et With (Nolock)
```